# Log axis with matplotlib - unexpected result

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to create a campbell diagramm (sound pressure level over time and frequency) with python.
That works fine as long as the y-axis that shows the frequency is linear.

When I switch to log (which is industry standard), the result looks unexpected. No matter what I enter for plt.ylim, the diagram looks the same with the distorted y-axis.

Since it looks the same both on my Win10 business box as well as on my private linux laptop, I assume that I am missing s.th. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

```
from scipy import signal

import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs=44100 # Samplerate
duration = 2  # seconds
leng=duration*fs
myrec = sd.rec(int(leng), samplerate=fs, channels=1, blocking=True)
myrec=myrec.flatten()
f, t, Zxx=signal.stft(myrec,fs,window='hann',nperseg=256)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Zxx), shading='gouraud')
plt.title('Campbell')
plt.ylabel('frequency [Hz]')
# Log plot - next two lines omitted in the linear plot
plt.ylim=(10,10000)
plt.yscale('log')
# 
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.show()
```

[Linear Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ouch.png)

[Log Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLosg.png)

As requested a modified version with fixed data.

```
from scipy import signal

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs=44100 # Samplerate
N = 88200 # 2s
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
carrier = amp * np.sin(2*np.pi*2.5e3*time)
f, t, Zxx=signal.stft(carrier,fs,window='hann',nperseg=256)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Zxx), shading='gouraud')
plt.title('Campbell')
plt.ylabel('Frequenz [Hz]')
# Linear
#plt.yscale('log')
#plt.ylim=(10,10000)
plt.xlabel('Zeit [s]')
plt.show()
```

The difference is the signal, it is now mathematically computed (so you don't have to import sounddevice any more). If you play this signal via loudspeaker you'd hear a high pitched (2.5 kHz) sinus sound for 2 seconds.

The linear diagramm looks as expected
[2.5 kHz Sine for 2s - ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk2Ob.png)

The log diagram (remove comments of the two lines after the #linear) looks exactly like in the example above and does not meet expectation.

Comment: Could you please review your plots? They don't appear to be the result of the example code you showed, so it's unclear what the unexpected results are.

Comment: Added comments for clearance - thanks for your input

Comment: > No matter what I enter for plt.ylim, the diagram looks the same with the distorted y-axis.
The y-axis in the linked diagrams appears as I would expect for a linear or log axis.

Neither plot seems to be effectively displaying any data.

Comment: To display data you have to have a microphone on the computer and create a sound (i.e. whistling). That works fine on the linear scale but log never shows the data and ylim does not control the axis.

Comment: Ah - thanks for that clarification on the input data. Could you use a dummy dataset or share an example dataset to recreate the problem to ascertain that it's an issue with the plotting rather than the input dataset? It's quite challenging to help solve a problem like this with such a specialized/unknown dataset, since the plotting code and plots look as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm blind.

The error lies in the format of ylim (the equal sign kills it).

With

```
plt.ylim(10,10000)
```

all works as expected.

[Y-axis in logarithmic as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf8cx.png)

Comment: Glad you figured it out - I totally didn't process that typo until you pointed it out!

Comment: Me neither. Got the hint from the matplotlib forum. Though I'd wish there was an error message instead of a crippled diagram